# Having trouble to exportmap in OpenLayer3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2

I'm trying to export the map, but I'm always getting the same error:

```
Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

The funny is that It works the first time... But when I do zoom It appears the error. I have the feeling that The map isn't refreshing or something like this... Really I'm not sure.

I have the following code:

```
var canvas = event.context.canvas;
var exportPNGElement = document.createElement('a');
exportPNGElement.download = 'Mapa.png';
exportPNGElement.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(exportPNGElement);
exportPNGElement.click();
document.body.removeChild(exportPNGElement);
```

What is wrong? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do your tiles have CORS Header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32040633/4640499